# Confused by get_the_terms to use in a new wp_query

Tags: terms

I'm working on a query to show related items op a CPT by the term assigned to the current post.

I already have the code to complete the query but don't get it why my initial code returns a NULL

To get the term assigned to the post I'm using this code

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy_name' );
```

If I do a var_dump of the `$terms` I get this in return

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#1423 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(5) ["name"]=> 
string(6) "Bilbao" ["slug"]=> string(6) "bilbao" ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(5) ["taxonomy"]=> string(15) "taxonomy_name" 
["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(2) 
["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }
```

To use the slug in my wp_query I thought I could use `$terms->slug`. However this returns a NULL.

After doing a search I found that this adjustment solved the issue `foreach ( $terms as $term )` and then `$term->slug`

I only don't understand why I should use the for each part and can't use the string of the `$terms` in my query. Can someone explain me that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$terms` is an array of terms, so PHP doesn't know what you mean when you say `$terms->slug`.

With foreach, you're iterating through this array. If you only care about the first element, you can simply use `$slug = $terms[0]->slug;`. This will get you in trouble when there are no terms, though, so you will want to make sure you only operate that if there are terms, with something like

```
$queryparams = array("post_type" => "mycpt");
if(count($terms)) {
    $slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    // modifiy your queryparams here
    $queryparams["tax_query"] = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In other words because you have an array of Objects(in your case you only have 1 object).
And you want to access that objects slug, and not the slug of the array.

Comment: Yeah, I got confused because it only returns one object, thanks